# How do I spring cloud gateway custom filter e2e test?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, e2e-testing, spring-cloud-gateway

I have implemented custom GatewayFilterFactory filter. But I don't know how to test this filter with e2e setup.

I have referenced [official spring-cloud-gateway `AddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactoryTests` test case code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/filter/factory/AddRequestHeaderGatewayFilterFactoryTests.java).

#### This is my custom filter code:

```
@Component
public class MyCustomFilter implements GatewayFilterFactory<MyCustomFilter.Config>, Ordered {

    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) {
        return new OrderedGatewayFilter((this::filter), getOrder());
    }

    public Mono<Void> filter(ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {
        /* do some filtering */
    }


    @Override
    public int getOrder() {
        return 1000;
    }

    @Override
    public Config newConfig() {
        return new Config(MyCustomFilter.class.getSimpleName());
    }

    public static getConfig() {
        return 
    }

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class Config {
        private String name;

        Config(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
}
```

#### And this is my test code:

`BaseWebClientTests` class look exactly the same as [official BaseWebClientTests class code](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/master/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/test/BaseWebClientTests.java)

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext
@ActiveProfiles("my-custom-filter")
public class MyCustomFilterTests extends BaseWebClientTests {
    @LocalServerPort
    protected int port = 0;

    protected WebTestClient testClient;

    protected WebClient webClient;

    protected String baseUri;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        setup(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(), "http://localhost:" + port);
    }

    protected void setup(ClientHttpConnector httpConnector, String baseUri) {
        this.baseUri = baseUri;
        this.webClient = WebClient.builder().clientConnector(httpConnector)
                .baseUrl(this.baseUri).build();
        this.testClient = WebTestClient
                .bindToServer(httpConnector)
                .baseUrl(this.baseUri)
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldFailByFilterTests() {
        /* This test should be failed but success :( */
        testClient.get().uri("/api/path")
                .exchange().expectBody(Map.class).consumeWith(result -> {
            /* do assertion */
        });
    }

    @EnableAutoConfiguration
    @SpringBootConfiguration
    @Import(DefaultTestConfig.class)
    public static class TestConfig {

        @Value("${test.uri}")
        String uri;

        @Bean
        public MyCustomFilter myCustomFilter() {
            return new MyCustomFilter();
        }

        @Bean
        public RouteLocator testRouteLocator(RouteLocatorBuilder builder, MyCustomFilter myCustomFilter) {
            return builder.routes().route("my_custom_filter",
                    r -> r.path("/api/path")
                            .filters(f -> f.filter(myCustomFilter.apply(new MyCustomFilter.Config("STRING"))))
                            .uri(uri))
                    .build();
        }

    }
}
```

#### Lastly Target controller looks like this:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/path")
public class HttpBinCompatibleController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public Mono<BodyData> identity() {
        return Mono.just(new BodyData("api success"));
    }

    @NoArgsConstructor
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @Getter
    static class BodyData {
        private String message;
    }
}
```

What I understand how this filter factory test code works is that

[image]

- custom filter: custom filter is setup inside `TestConfig` class `testRouteLocator` method
- target controller: target controller is defined as `HttpBinCompatibleController` class

`testClient` sends the request, and custom should do some filtering, then target controller should receive the request from `testClient`.

What I expect from this `shouldFailByFilterTests` TC is that before request from `testClient` is sent to target controller, that request should be rejected by `MyCustomFilter`. **But the request is sent to the target controller.**

I think the request from `testClient` is not proxied by `testRouteLocator` but I'm not sure

#### Question

1. What is the cause of this problem?
2. Is there another way to test my own custom filter?

Comment: Have you put a breakpoint in your filter?

Comment: yep. and it does not stop on that breakpoint.

Comment: We do this all the time in spring cloud gateway iteself. Can you set `logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway=TRACE` and see if you can tell anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was related to the **version incompatibility** between Spring Boot and Spring Cloud.

I was using Spring Boot version 2.1.7 and Spring Cloud version Greenwich.SR2.

Then I found this 'Release train Spring Boot compatibility' table on this [link](https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud)

Before I've noticed version incompatibility, for using `@Configuration(proxyBeanMethods = false)` feature, upgraded Spring Boot version to 2.2.x.

The solution is using 2.1.x branch [BaseWebClientTests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/2.1.x/spring-cloud-gateway-core/src/test/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/test/BaseWebClientTests.java) class.